# Automatic scatter plot with lines connecting points?

Tags: web-apps, plotting

I have a data set of thousands of number pair tuples. (X,Y)

I need software that will automatically plot out a data point for each unique number in the data set, along with an arrow pointing from point X to point Y for each tuple in the set.

It sounds simple enough that there should be something for this out there. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Not a web app but [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) should do the trick. According to the program website " Gnuplot is a portable command-line driven graphing utility for Linux, OS/2, MS Windows, OSX, VMS, and many other platforms. " If i understand correctly, you want something like the last figure of this [link](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/lines_arrows.html). You can easily find tutorials on how to use the app.